# How to add info window for custom overlays?

Tags: maps, overlay, infowindow

I have implemented a custom overlay. I want to add an event which will pop an info window when I click the overlay.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('okmap'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 35.0000, lng: 103.0000}
  });

  for (var n in nodes) {
      var myMarker = new MyMarker(map, {latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(nodes[n][0], nodes[n][1]), 
                                    image: 'assets/img/light-green.png',
                                    labelText: (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0)});
      markers.push(myMarker);
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: n
      });
      myMarker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, myMarker);
      });
  }
}
```

But it is not working!

Comment: I added infoWindow function inside the marker draw function where I am drawing my custom div as a marker. It  was showing infoWindow but its position is disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a simliar problem some time back. Here are two things that helped me.
I am considering the main overlay element to be a `div`.

In your `MyMarker.draw`  function  make sure that you are using a pane that has access to the DOM events.e.g.

```
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#initialize for more details.

Make sure you define an event listener, also in the `MyMarker.draw`  function.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
});
```